# How to increment based on checkbox and input values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a button that will change based on how many checkboxes and input values are entered/selected.

For example, I have a button html that changes based on how many items are selected

- Buy (0 items selected)
- Buy 1 item (1 item selected/entered)
- Buy x items (x items selected/entered)

using a buyCounter data variable set to 0 currently. I would like to increase/decrease this counter based on the checkbox/input values.

If a checkbox is selected, it counts as +1, if deselected -1.

On the input, it takes any value entered and adds its to the counter. For example if 4 is entered on an input, add +4 to the counter.

Currently not focused on if that number is more than the amount allowed, really just trying to figure out the counter part.

I created this example below in codepen to get close enough to what I'm trying to achieve. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QooWZV?&editable=true&editors=101

**TEMPLATE**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td v-if="props.item.available > 1"  style="display:inline-flex">
          <v-text-field style="width:5%; padding-bottom:10px;"></v-text-field> of {{ props.item.available }}
        </td>
        <td v-else>
          <v-checkbox
            v-on:change="increment($event)" 
            v-model="props.selected"
            primary
            hide-details
          ></v-checkbox>
        </td>       
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
        <v-layout row wrap class="">
            <v-flex xs4 class="text-xs-left">
            <v-btn  
             v-if="buyCounter < 1" 
             color="blue-grey" 
             class="white--text">
            Buy
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn  
             v-else-if="buyCounter > 0 && buyCounter < 2" 
             color="blue-grey" 
             class="white--text">
              Buy {{ buyCounter }} Item
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn  
              v-else-if="buyCounter > 1" 
              color="blue-grey" 
              class="white--text">
              Buy {{ buyCounter }} Items
            </v-btn>           
            </v-flex>   
            <v-flex xs4 class="text-xs-center">     
            </v-flex>           
            <v-flex xs4 class="text-xs-right">                  
            </v-flex>                                   
        </v-layout>     
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [],
      buyCounter: 0,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Count',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: ''
        }, 
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
          available: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
          available: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
          available: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
          available: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
          available: 3
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
          available: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
          available: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
          available: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
          available: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
          available: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    increment(event){
        console.log(this.selected);
        const isChecked = event;

        if(isChecked){
            this.buyCounter++;
        }else{
            this.buyCounter--;
        } 

    }
  }
})
```

Looking to create a button that recognizes how many items are about to be bought.